# How do I create a join using a 'greater than' and a 'group by'?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have a table containing a series of names, events and dates. I've created a new field '`evt5_date`' which is related to a specific event (`evt5`).

Each name can have several events the timing of each is recorded in `evt_date` field.
Two events `evt1` and `evt2` are related to `evt5`.

I want to insert the date of the first occurrence of an `evt5` into all `evt1` and `evt2` rows preceding the `evt5`. If there is no `evt5` after the `evt1` or `evt2` then the field is left empty.

All this must be done for each `name`. There are a few thousand different names. I've only show 2 in the data below

**Current table data** - no values in evt5_date

```
name      evt_date       event    evt5_date
name-1    2010-06-30     evt1     
name-1    2009-10-30     evt5
name-1    2009-09-30     evt2      
name-1    2009-06-30     evt5          
name-1    2009-03-30     evt5     
name-1    2009-02-28     evt2     
name-1    2009-01-30     evt1     
name-2    2005-05-30     evt2
name-2    2005-03-30     evt5
name-2    2005-01-30     evt1
```

**How I'd like it to look** - values in evt5_date field

```
name      evt_date       event    evt5_date
name-1    2010-06-30     evt1     
name-1    2009-10-30     evt5
name-1    2009-09-30     evt2     2009-10-30 
name-1    2009-06-30     evt5          
name-1    2009-03-30     evt5     
name-1    2009-02-28     evt2     2009-03-30
name-1    2009-01-30     evt1     2009-03-30
name-2    2005-05-30     evt2
name-2    2005-03-30     evt5
name-2    2005-01-30     evt1     2005-03-31
```

I attempted to perform the update with the code below, but I didn't know how to specify the linkage between the date of evt5 being greater than the evt_date of evt1 and evt2 while also grouping by the evt5 in order to obtain the evt_date relating to the most recent evt5.

I also need to group by name since the events are specific to each name.

```
update mytable as t1
set t1.evt5_date = (select min(t2.evt_date) from mytable as t2
                    where t2.event = 'evt5' AND
                           t2.evt_date > t1.evt_date
                    group by name)
where
  t1.event in ('evt1', 'evt2')
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**Update final solution** - some minor changes to answer provided by @biziclop to maintain the integrity of the `name`

```
UPDATE mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT
             a.name, a.evt_date,
        MIN( b.evt_date ) AS nearest_date
      FROM       mytable AS a
      INNER JOIN mytable AS b ON b.event = 'evt5'
                            AND b.evt_date > a.evt_date
                            AND a.name = b.name       -- needed this additional condition
      GROUP BY a.name, a.evt_date                     -- added 'a.name' to 'group by' 
    ) AS nearest_dates 
       ON nearest_dates.evt_date = t1.evt_date AND
         nearest_dates.name = t1.name                 -- added this additional condition
SET t1.evt5_date = nearest_dates.nearest_date
WHERE t1.event IN ('evt1', 'evt2');
```

Comment: who is a2.evt5_date???, I don't get it, you have update T1 and set a2?

Comment: @jcho360 - sorry that was a typo, it's supposed to be 't1'. Fixed now.

Comment: can you put some structure and data in sqlfiddle and share it?

Comment: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/

Comment: @biziclop, thanks for your help guys. I'm sorry that I wasn't clearer but the values in the NAME field do vary which is why I had the 'group by name' statement. I've updated the questions above. I also had a look at the code you provided on sqlfiddle (awesome site, I'd never been there before! so thanks for sharing it with me). I've update the data and re-ran the code. It almost works, but I need to add the 'name' condition in somewhere. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @jcho360 - thanks mate, I couldn't tag you in the above comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed your update statement, I think it works now. I omitted the `GROUP BY name` part, because it wasn't meaningful in your version.

```
UPDATE mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        a.evt_date,
        MIN( b.evt_date ) AS nearest_date
      FROM       mytable AS a
      INNER JOIN mytable AS b ON b.event = 'evt5'
                            AND b.evt_date > a.evt_date
      GROUP BY a.evt_date
    ) AS nearest_dates ON nearest_dates.evt_date = t1.evt_date
SET t1.evt5_date = nearest_dates.nearest_date
WHERE t1.event IN ('evt1', 'evt2');
```

First some verifications:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/309ac/6

The final `UPDATE` query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80c3c/1

Comment: thanks a lot for this and for the great explanation on sqlfiddle. I made some minor changes to account for the varying names (as shown in the updated question). I really appreciate the help.